# Starting a method at launch

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class called databaseConnection which I want to be launched/executed when the application starts, it seems I should call it from the start method  ( which I call MainApp ) but I can't seem to find the right way to do it, hence my question

I think it's quite easy but I really cant get it

databaseConnection:

```
package albertheijnhandterminal;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 *
 * @author Stanly
 */
public class databaseConnection {

    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AlbertHeijnHandterminal;create=true;user=StanlySuijk;password=hoi55455";
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static Statement statement = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createConnection();
        //insertUsers("");
        //selectUsers();
        //shutdown();

    }

    private static void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            //Get a connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }

    }

}
```

MainApp:

```
package albertheijnhandterminal;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import static javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect;

/*
 1
 9 @author Stanly
 9 
 9
 */
public class MainApp extends Application {


    public static FrameController theFrameController = null;

    static StackPane displayPane;

    public static Connection connection = null;
    public static Statement statement = null;
    public static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    public static ResultSet resultSet = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Frame.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Albert Heijn Handterminal");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I am only programming for about 6 months so if you see some improvements in my code that would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a static method launch in MainApp  and call the  method createConnection using databaseConnection.createConnection();

Comment: you can call `databaseConnection.main(null);` from every method/class in your code. updated code: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        databaseConnection.main(null);
launch(args);
    }`

Comment: You can call your method before launch.

Comment: As already pointed, you're never instantiating your databaseConnection object in your MainApp. Here is a simple example of a javafx app with a database. It may be useful https://www.swtestacademy.com/database-operations-javafx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your App is `MainApp` class, then that class should have the main method. Then you should do the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   databaseConnection db = new databaseConnection ();
   db.createConnection();
   launch(args);
}
```

Or calling `main` method of the other class.

If no args are needed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    databaseConnection.main(null);
    launch(args);
}
```

If args are needed

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    databaseConnection.main(args);
    launch(args);
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

As James_D pointed out in the comments:

> Under some circumstances you might want the application to be launched using a "pure JavaFX launch", which would bypass the main() method entirely

In this case, it would be better to move this

```
databaseConnection db = new databaseConnection ();
db.createConnection();
```

to the `start()` method.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    databaseConnection db = new databaseConnection ();
    db.createConnection();

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Frame.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("Albert Heijn Handterminal");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: you can use 2 `main` methods. there is no problem in doing so. it would actually shorten the call to 1 line (`databaseConnection.main(null);` or `databaseConnection.main(args);`)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes you are right. I updated my answer, adding that. Thanks!

Comment: In a JavaFX application, it is probably better to move `databaseConnection db = new databaseConnection(); db.createConnection();` to the `start()` (or `init()`) methods. Under some circumstances you might want the application to be launched using a "pure JavaFX launch", which would bypass the `main()` method entirely.

Comment: @James_D Good point! I updated my answer to include that. Thanks!